# What is the faster way to search for sequence of numbers in a 2d vector?

Tags: c++, algorithm, c++11, search, vector

Given a 2d array(**the array can be larger than 10k*10k**) with integer values, What is the faster way to search for a given sequence of numbers in the array?

Assume the 2d array which is in the file is read into a big 1d vector and is accessed as big_matrix(row*x+width).
There are 3 types of searches I would like to do on the same 2d array. They are Search Ordered, Search Unordered, Search Best Match. Here's my approach to each of the search functions.

**Search Ordered**: This function finds all the rows in which given number sequence(order of numbers matters) is present. Here's the KMP method to find the given number sequence I implemented:

```
void searchPattern(std::vector<int> const &pattern, std::vector<int> const &big_matrix, int begin, int finish,
                         int width, std::vector<int> &searchResult) {

    auto M = (int) pattern.size();
    auto N = width; // size of one row

    while (begin < finish) {
        int i = 0;
        int j = 0;
        while (i < N) {
            if (pattern[j] == big_matrix[(begin * width) + i]) {
                j++;
                i++;
            }
            if (j == M) {
                searchResult[begin] = begin;
                begin++;
                break;
            } else if (i < N && pattern[j] != big_matrix[(begin * width) + i]) {
                if (j != 0)
                    j = lps[j - 1]; // lookup table as in KMP
                else
                    i = i + 1;
            }
        }
        if (j != M) {
            searchResult[begin] = -1;
            begin++;
        }
    }
}
```

Complexity: O(m*n); m is the number of rows, n is the number of cols

**Search Unordered/Search Best Match**: This function finds all the rows in which given number sequence is present(order of numbers doesn't matter).
Here I am sorting the large array initially and will just sort only the input array during the search.

```
void SearchUnordered/BestMatch(std::vector<int> const &match, std::vector<int> const &big_matrix_sorted, int begin, int finish,
                     int width, std::vector<int> &searchResult) {
    std::vector<int>::iterator it;
    std::vector<int> v(match.size() + width);
    while (begin < finish) {
        it = std::set_intersection(match.begin(), match.end(), big_matrix_sorted.begin() + begin * width,
                                   big_matrix_sorted.begin() + begin * width + width, v.begin());
        v.resize(it - v.begin());
        if (v.size() == subseq.size())
        searchResult[begin] = begin;
        else
        searchResult[begin] = -1;
        begin++;
        /* For search best match the last few lines will change as follows:
      searchResult[begin] = (int) v.size();
      begin++; and largest in searchResult will be the result */
    }
}
```

Complexity: O(m*(l + n)); l - the length of the pattern, m is the number of rows, n is the number of cols.

**Preprocessing of big_matrix**(Constructing lookup table, storing a sorted version of it. You're allowed to do any pre-processing stuff.) **is not taken into consideration**. How can I improve the complexity(to **O(log (m*n)**) of these search functions?

Comment: *"Assume the 2d array which is in file is read into a big 1d vector and is accessed as big_matrix(row*x+width)"* - if we can assume that then I think it's just a `1d` array problem.

Comment: @Galik You can think it that way but You have to return the row indices which matches the search criteria.

Comment: I would think the slow part will be the searching. The math to discover the row and column from the absolute offset will happen in the order of hundred millionths of a second. Did you try [std::search](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/search)? You might benefit from using the *boyer_more_searcher*.

Comment: @Galik Yes, I have tried `std::search` but I didn't find drastic change in the performance. My implementation clearly isn't making use of the fact that they're numbers. I am doing something similar to what we do with the strings. Is there a way to reduce the search space? One hint I received is to build a lookup table but I didn't get any lead.

Comment: Did you specifically try the *boyer_more* algorithm? It is supposed to do well on large samples. It doesn't visit every element but finds opportunities to "skip ahead".

Comment: @Galik Yes, It was better than `KMP` and `std::search` but the complexity is still O(m*n) for entire array. Is there a way to reduce the search space and improve the complexity?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/181472/discussion-between-adithya-potlapelli-and-galik).

Comment: I don't think you can ever escape from the fact that if you add a new row, you have to search all of it and that search will be dependent on the number of columns. So you will always end up multiplying the column based search time by the number of rows. (for the unordered search)

Comment: @Galik So there isn't any other efficient way to determine whether a row matches the search criteria or not? Even lookup table/any preprocessing isn't going to help much?

Comment: Convert rows to a graph, with roots sorted. The searches become O(m\*log(n)\*p) where p is the length of the searched sequence worst case if lots of rows match, or O(m*log(n)) if only a few rows match. With a graph where leafs list repeats, the cost becomes O(log(n)) with no matches, or O(log(n)*p) with any matches. In other words: pretty damn fast.

Comment: For your first search, if you have a pattern then why don't you search for it instead of comparing column by column (use memcmp) this will reduce the number of comparisons. You could also do in your preprocessing a sum of the columns by row, and then use it to skip rows directly.

Comment: @JoãoAugusto Yes, `memcmp` will reduce the number of comparisons but there won't be drastic change in the performance. The use-case scenario is given a matrix, I will be performing millions of search on it with varying inputs. I have to pre-compute what I can(memory usage isn't important).

Comment: @AdithyaPotlapelli Did you profiled to see the result ? What's the range of the integers, full 4 bytes? If for example the width is less than a cache line you could probably increment the width so that you only get complete rows in every cache line. In your precalcs you could also try to know the min and max value to skip lines.

Comment: I have three questions; 1) “I will be performing millions of search on it with varying inputs.” Does the word “inputs” here mean "patterns" ? 2) If so, how many patterns we should search ? 3) How many patterns can we know before starting search ?

Comment: @Hiroki Yes, It means "patterns". The number of patterns is not known in advance. The linchpin here is building a lookup table and reducing the search space.

Comment: Thx. I understand but I have no idea rather than well-known algorithms, KMP, BM, RK, backward nondeterministic dawg matching algorithm, ...

Comment: @Hiroki None of them take advantage of the special characteristics of each search and fact that they're numbers.

Comment: Thx again. In Rabin-Karp algorithm characters are treated as integers (`char`) and substrings which has the same hash value is searched. So I thought that the situation is not so different from substring search and the RK is more suitable if the current problem is the multiple pattern search.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to do it faster overall, but already have the right algorithm. You may get some performance by just optimising the code (memory allocations, removing duplicate operations if the compiler didn't etc.). For example there *may* be a gain by removing the two `big_matrix[(row * width) + i]` and assigning it to a local variable. Be careful to profile and measure realistic cases.

For bigger gains, threads can be an option. You can process here one row at a time, so should be roughly linear speedup with the number of cores. C++ 11 has `std::async`, which can handle some of the work for launching threads and getting results, rather than dealing with `std::thread` yourself or platform specific mechanisms. There are some other newer things that may be useful as well in newer versions of C++.

```
void searchPatternRow(std::vector<int> const &pattern, std::vector<int> const &big_matrix, int row, int width, std::vector<int> &searchResult);
void searchPattern(std::vector<int> const &pattern, std::vector<int> const &big_matrix, int begin, int finish, int width, std::vector<int> &searchResult)
{
    std::vector<std::future<void>> futures;
    for (int row = begin; row < finish; ++row)
        std::async([&, row]() { searchPatternRow(pattern, big_matrix, row, width, searchResult);  });
    for (auto &future : futures) future.wait(); // Note, also implicit when the future from async gets destructed
}
```

To improve threaded efficiency you may want to batch and search say 10 rows. There are also some considerations with threads writing to the same cache line for `searchResult`.

Answer (score 1):

When searching for exact match, you can do this quite efficient by use of what I will call a "**moving hash**".

When you search, you calculate a hash on your search string, and at the same time you keep calculating a moving hash on the data you are searching. When comparing you then first compares the hash, and only if that match, you then go on and compare the actual data.

Now **the tick** is to chose an hash algorithm that can **easily be updated** each time you move one spot, instead of recalculating everything. An example of such a hash is eg. the sum of all the digits.

If I have the following array: `012345678901234567890` and I want to find `34567` in this array, I could define the hash as the sum of all the digits in the search string. This would give a hash of `25` (3+4+5+6+7). I would then search through the array and keep updating a running hash on the array. The first hash in the array would be `10` (0+1+2+3+4) and the second hash would be `15` (1+2+3+4+5). But instead of recalculte the second hash, I can just update the previous hash by adding 5 (the new digit) and subtracting 0 (the old digit).

As updating the "running hash" is **O(1)** you can speed up the process considerable if you have a good Hash algorithm that don't give many false hits. The simple sum I use as hash is properbly too simple, but other methodes allows for this updating of the hash, eg **XOR** ..